# Why do I get this IAM error when deploying my terraform template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam

I want to deploy my terraform template on my ubuntu docker container. I set the keys in the container in env vars, in terraform and in `/.aws/credentials`. At first I had keys with admin rights, but then I also tried the root keys without success.

My terraform version I have tried is 0.14 and 1.2.6

This is the error:

> status code: 403, request id: xxx, host id: xxx =: timestamp=2022-08-12T16:18:50.169Z 2022/08/12 16:18:50 [DEBUG] aws_s3_bucket.root_bucket: apply errored, but we're indicating that via the Error pointer rather than returning it: Error creating S3 bucket: AccessDenied: Access Denied   status code: 403, request id: xxx, host id: xxx =

This is the code and the json:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "root_bucket" {
  bucket = var.bucket_name
  acl    = "public-read"
  policy = templatefile("templates/s3-policy.json", { bucket = var.bucket_name })

  website {
    redirect_all_requests_to = "https://www.${var.domain_name}"
  }

  tags = var.common_tags
}

# json below
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket}/*"
        }
    ]
}

# provider file below 
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.2.6"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }

  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "skapawebb-terraform"
    key    = "prod/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "eu-north-1"
    access_key = “xxx”
    secret_key = “xxx" 
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-north-1"
  access_key = “xxx”
  secret_key = “xxx”  
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "acm_provider"
  region = "us-east-1"
}
```

Comment: What is the code?

Comment: How did you configure `aws` provider block and which version?

Comment: I am currently running v.1.2.6
added the provider file in description
@BinhNguyen

Comment: @iKnowItAll have you ever tried creating your S3 bucket from AWS Console? I tested your code and not any issues from my side.

Comment: Thanks for testing .. Will try that tomorrow morning and write what happens .. I will just have to figure out how I can do what terraform does manually in cloudformation @BinhNguyen

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens because of two reasons:

1. You are adding public policy to your bucket, and
2. You have enabled [block public access settings for your account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/configuring-block-public-access-account.html) for the account.

You have to disable the block public access settings for your account, before you can create any buckets with public policies.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

I tried that. Made sure all those 4 settings are turned off. Still same error though. Not sure what to do atm.. any idea? @Marcin